# Is there a .NET class for buffering large files?

Tags: .net, optimization

I need to save a file (20 Mb - 300 Mb) in a DB obtained from network. I need a fast solution in C#, so I need to buffer in-memory to avoid storing in a temporary file system location.

But just using an array is not a solution, because I need to avoid allocation of continuous space in memory because of heap fragmentation. This is for a back end server with parallel user access. So I can't preallocate space in the beginning of program life.

Is there a C# class from the standard framework - like an in-memory stream - that is based on a data structure similar to several non-continuous chunks of continuous arrays? Is there a class that can automatically utilize non-large pieces of fragmented memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of anything in the *current* system libraries that provides this functionality - you'd need to implement it manually.

What you're after is something that the "pipelines" project (a reworking of the IO stack for high-performance systems) will deliver. This API is very experimental with no specific ETA, but:

- `MemoryPool<byte>` (abstract) / `MemoryPool` (concrete) provide an API model for leasing chunks of contiguous memory
- `ReadOnlyBuffer` describes a wrapper over multiple slices from multiple chunks, exposing them as a single entity

This API is very incomplete and experimental right now, but can be played with. It is what the ASP.NET MVC "Kestrel" http server is built on top of. There isn't really any documentation right now, but I've [started this](https://mgravell.github.io/pipelines.docs/).

For reference, "pipelines" is what has inspired a lot of the recent C# changes including `ref this`, `in`, `in this` and `ref struct` - and JIT changes for `Span<T>`. So: it looks likely to actually happen.